# Releasing dynamically added UILabel

Tags: objective-c, iphone

I am adding a no. of UILable dynamically to my view like this

```
UILabel *test = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(x, y, 50, 50)];  
[self.view addSubview:tick];
```

Is it necessary to release these UILabel from memory in viewDidUnLoad and dealloc, if yes how i will release them? how i will get their reference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.

Since `self.view` already `-retain`ed the label in `-addSubview:`, you can `-release` it immediately.

```
UILabel *test = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(x, y, 50, 50)];  
[self.view addSubview:test];
[test release]; // <--
```